# Error 65 trying to initialize firebase into my react-native project

Tags: xcode, firebase, react-native

i am trying now for 2 days to set up firebase for my react-native project. I tried a lot of different solutions which i found here or on github, but without any results.

Now i just created a new project, without installing any packages or other stuff. Just followed [THIS](https://rnfirebase.io) tutorial.

My Android Simulator is working without any errors. Everytime i want to build my iOS simulator

```
npx react-native run-ios)
```

i just get the following error:

```
> info Found Xcode workspace "NooMi.xcworkspace"
> info No booted devices or simulators found. Launching first available simulator...
> info Launching iPhone SE (3rd generation) (iOS 16.4)
> info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace NooMi.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NooMi -destination id=DDE6DDDD-3BA9-4AD9-8E0B-E891BA70D038")
> 
> info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 
> 
> error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening NooMi.xcworkspace.
> Command line invocation:
> >!     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace NooMi.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme NooMi -destination id=DDE6DDDD-3BA9-4AD9-8E0B-E891BA70D038
> 
> User defaults from command line:
> IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
> 
> Prepare packages
> 
> Computing target dependency graph and provisioning inputs
> 
> Create build description
> Build description signature: 40a56b9c3b78933335485eaf244dbee1
> Build description path: /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/40a56b9c3b78933335485eaf244dbee1.xcbuilddata
> 
> note: Building targets in dependency order
> error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/CallbackWrapper.h'
> note: Target 'ReactCommon' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/bridging/CallbackWrapper.h' to '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/CallbackWrapper.h'
> note: Target 'ReactCommon' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/CallbackWrapper.h' to '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/CallbackWrapper.h'
> error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/LongLivedObject.h'
> note: Target 'ReactCommon' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/bridging/LongLivedObject.h' to '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/LongLivedObject.h'
> note: Target 'ReactCommon' (project 'Pods') has copy command from '/Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/LongLivedObject.h' to '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/LongLivedObject.h'
> ClangStatCache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.4.sdk /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache
> cd /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/ios
> >!     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang-stat-cache /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.4.sdk -o /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDKStatCaches.noindex/iphonesimulator16.4-20E238-.sdkstatcache
> 
> warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods')
> warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NooMi' from project 'NooMi')
> warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NooMi' from project 'NooMi')
> warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'NooMi' from project 'NooMi')
> warning: duplicate output file '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/CallbackWrapper.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/CallbackWrapper.h /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/CallbackWrapper.h (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
> warning: duplicate output file '/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/LongLivedObject.h' on task: CpHeader /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NooMi-aswnibsigxrnzwdntzyveemvooad/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon/ReactCommon.framework/Headers/LongLivedObject.h /Users/xxx/Documents/GitHub/react-native-VermittlungsApp/NooMi/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/react/nativemodule/core/ReactCommon/LongLivedObject.h (in target 'ReactCommon' from project 'Pods')
> warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'fmt' from project 'Pods')
> warning: Run script build phase 'Create Symlinks to Header Folders' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
> 
> 2023-08-25 12:43:40.649 xcodebuild[63634:9417826] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
> xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
> platform:iOS Simulator, id:DDE6DDDD-3BA9-4AD9-8E0B-E891BA70D038, OS:16.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
> platform:iOS Simulator, id:DDE6DDDD-3BA9-4AD9-8E0B-E891BA70D038, OS:16.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
> BUILD FAILED **
>
```

I tried to delete the build folder, install pod again etc. nothing helped.

Hope we can find the solution!

I tried to delete the build folder, deleted and installed pod again, created a new project